getting data from resolver in angular guard
I have following problem:
While routing to this path it gets me to appropriate component with resolver you can see below.

this component has its guard and I want to reach the data from resoler in this productConfigGuard

as for now it looks like this cause Im trying just to console log this data 
and this is where strange magic begins. Because what I see in console is :

As you can see when Im unfolding ActivatedRouteSnapshot object there is logicalProductData in data object, but when Im trying to get this data directly in no way I cant have it. Its always undefined... Is it some kind of nasty bug ? Because its incomprehensible to me
